# Change directories verbosely?

Tags: shell, cd-command, macos

I am logging every action performed in a bash script to a logfile. I would like to have `cd` verbosely change directories so I can record the output to the log.

Kind of like this:

```
iMac:~ leetbacoon$ cd -v /new\ path
cd: /Users/leetbacoon -> /new path
iMac:new path leetbacoon$
```

Sadly `cd` lacks a verbose flag. Any idea on how to get something like this to work?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You may find the shell `$OLDPWD` shell variable useful (defined by POSIX). For example, you could define a shell function overriding the *original* `cd` command:

```sh
cd() { command cd "$@" && printf '%s -> %s\n' "${OLDPWD}" "${PWD}"; }
```

Excerpt from the Unix [man page](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/cd.html) you should read:

> If, during the execution of the above steps, the `PWD` environment variable is set, the `OLDPWD` environment variable shall also be set to the value of the old working directory (that is the current working directory immediately prior to the call to `cd`).

Comment: Is it possible for the function to add a `-v`/`--verbose` flag to `cd`?

Comment: @leetbacoon it is almost certainly possible - it would take some careful parsing (beyond my abilities) to separate out the `-v` and pass any remaining parameters to the underlying `cd` builtin